# How to edit <h1> via PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I would like to accomplish this without mixing my HTML and PHP, so no in-line PHP code, etc.

I have a very simple question, at least it seems simple. I know you can use $_POST to get a variety of HTML values out of their elements with PHP, such as getting the year from the HTML page, `$year = $_POST['year'];`. My question is this:

What would you say for the elements that don't have an assigned value? for instance:

How would I change the contents:

```
<h1> Welcome to the Super Bowl Winner Search Years 2000 - 2015! <br />  <br />
                Select the year, see the winning team!</h1>
```

after the user has clicked the submit button that calls the .php script.

`<form action = "http://localhost/myPrograms/superBowl.php" method = "post" >`

In the beginning, `$year` holds the value of the HTML element year, `<select name = "year" >` (my drop box)

Would you just do something similar to `$h1 = $_POST['h1']`? this doesn't seem right and would leave me still confused on how to actually EDIT the .innerHTML of `<h1>`? not just create a new h1

Thanks!

Comment: Just put `<h1> <?php echo $_POST['h1']; ?> </h1>`.

Comment: If you don't want to mix HTML and PHP you will have to use Javascript to accomplish what you want

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you want to change into what

Comment: @aharen Saw it. That's why I didn't post it as an answe.

Comment: `<h1> Welcome to the Super Bowl Winner Search Years 2000 - 2015! <br />  <br />
                Select the year, see the winning team!</h1>` > User selects the year from the drop box > user clicks submit > (desired)`<h1> The text has changed!<br />  <br />
                </h1>`

Comment: Fear not the use of php. and if you want to take kumar's advise, I would do it as a ternary: <h1> <?php echo isset($_POST['h1']) ? $_POST['h1'] : 'Welcome to the Super Bowl Winner Search Years 2000 - 2015!<br /><br />Select the year, see the winning team!'; ?> </h1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all three files in the same directory.  And then view super_bowl.php in your browser.

I'm using a made up template language to substitute strings into html templates.

template.html

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>@@TITLE@@</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>@@HEADING@@</h1>
            @@CONTENT@@
            @@FORM@@
        </body>
    </html>
```

form.html

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Winner Picker</legend>
        <label for="year">Select the year to see the winning team:</label>
        <select name="year">
          <option value="2010">2010</option> 
          <option value="2011">2011</option>
          <option value="2012">2012</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="See Winner" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

super_bowl.php

```
<?php

$winners = array(
    '2010' => 'The Braves',
    '2011' => 'Blue Beards',
    '2012' => 'Fever Pitchers'
);

$year = isset($_GET['year']) && array_key_exists($_GET['year'], $winners) 
    ? $_GET['year']
    : null;

$winner = ! is_null($year)
    ? $winners[$year] 
    : null;

$template = file_get_contents('template.html');
$form     = file_get_contents('form.html');

$output = strtr($template, array(
    '@@TITLE@@' => 'Super Bowl Winners Search Years 2000 - 2015',
    '@@FORM@@' => $form,
    '@@HEADING@@' => 
        ! is_null($year) 
        ? 'Superbowl winner for the year: ' . $year 
        : 'Welcome to the Super Bowl Winner Search Years 2000 - 2015!',
    '@@CONTENT@@' => 
        ! is_null($winner)
        ? 'Were the ' . $winner . '.'
        : null
    ));

// Print page output
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to just put:

```
<h1> <?php echo (isset($_POST['h1'])) ? isset($_POST['h1'] : 'Welcome to the Super Bowl Winner Search Years 2000 - 2015! <br />  <br /> Select the year, see the winning team!' ; ?> </h1>
```

But still, since you insist, go ahead and read...

Only way PHP can interact with your HTML after loading is through AJAX, that too the client side requests the server and gets the information. So what you need to do technically is, you need to fire up an AJAX call after your page is loaded and get the info. This is far most the crazy way of loading stuff.

Anyways, you can do this using jQuery. Yes, I would *request* you to use jQuery for AJAX functions so that you don't mess up with the browser.

```
$("h1").load("/php-file.php?get=h1");
```

And in the `php-file.php`:

```
<?php
  if ($_GET["get"] == "h1")
    die('Welcome to the Super Bowl Winner Search Years 2000 - 2015! <br />  <br /> Select the year, see the winning team!');
?>
```

I really cannot think of any other better way to answer this question.